# A man and his dog

Tags: lateral-thinking

Whenever James takes his dog for a walk, before attaching the dog's lead, he stands by the front door and calls the dog's name towards him. He does this even if he can physically feel the dog already waiting there. Otherwise, James might die. What's the explanation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think

> **James is blind**.He have to make sure it is his dog , so that the dog will take care of him while walking.James might die of road accidents if the dog is not his dog.

Comment: He can feel that the dog is there. Are you saying he can't be sure it really is his dog unless he calls it?

Comment: @HughMeyers why not? It's a possibility.

Comment: identifying with touching is difficult unless the dog reacts friendly..!

Comment: How could somebody else's dog be at your house?

Comment: He could have more than one dog, only one of which is relevantly trained

Comment: It is a possibility. I was just trying to clarify that was what the answer was. The way I read the question, it's not so much why did he need the dog but why did he call it when he could feel it was there.

Comment: If James has multiple dogs and is completely incapable of differentiating them by touch (unlikely), then calling its name is no guarantee of getting the right dog. E.g. 1: There are already two dogs next to him, one of which is the right dog. E.g. 2: He has no dogs next to him, calls out the name, and two come together. E.g. 3: He has the right dog next to him, calls out its name, and a second dog comes out of curiosity. I'm sure there are many other variants like this.

Comment: An even bigger problem is that the wording of the puzzle doesn't support the idea that he doesn't recognize the dog by touch. He "calls **the** dog's name" even if "he can physically feel **the** dog".  The word **the** means that we're talking about the same dog here, so he knows it is the right one. It would need to read "he can physically feel **a** dog" for there to be uncertainty.

Comment: To be clear, I think there is more than one possible answer to the question. I think this is one of the possibilities. I'm just suggesting that it be good to say that his dog has an evil twin or the dog is new and he is staying with his sister who has 5 dogs or it's winter, he's wearing gloves and the dog barks when called so he can recognize its voice. Something to explain the confusion. This is a good answer.

Comment: @HughMeyers A simple explanation would be the dog is trained to fetch its harness when its owner calls it from the door.

Comment: @Will True but then you have to justify "might die". If the dog doesn't bring the harness would he go out without it? Would he trip and break his neck looking for it?

Comment: @HughMeyers I took the whole puzzle to be "[James does sequence of steps before going out]. [If James does not do this this sequence of steps, but goes out anyway], James might die." I think we may have interpreted the "otherwise" differently, and the edits since the puzzle was first posted may be source of confusion.

Answer (score 14):

Simplest explanation:

> The dog is trained to kill anyone who tries to leash it without saying its name first. I assume he is blind because the question says "physically feel" instead of "see". Even if James is blind, I'm sure he could identify his dog by touch.

Comment: I prefer this answer over JAVY's because it solves the various problems with that one. It's probably not the intended answer though, given that he merely "might" die.

Comment: @JBentley Thanks. Depending on how big the dog is and how tough James is, I figured he could well survive the attack. And pretty much all blind people can get by without their dogs. The dogs just make it easier.

Answer (score 6):

> Whenever James goes out with the dog he enables a complicated and lethal system of booby traps. The system is voice-activated using the dog's name. The important part is standing by the front door; if he's elsewhere in the house he'll trigger the traps.

Comment: Damn it, they found out how it works! Now i need to change my system...

Answer (score 6):

All answers here seem legit. Here's my shot:

> I think James is not blind but **the dog is blind** and can attack if some stranger touches him. So James calls the dog's name and the dog knows that his owner is approaching him.

Comment: * J a m e s . !!

Comment: The dog would be able to smell and recognize his owner even if it's blind

Comment: @Marc (s)he can have a smell imparement as well.

Comment: James is a seeing-eye human.

Answer (score 3):

> James lives in an alternate universe where dogs rule over the human race. The dog is blind and needs James to guide him around the futuristic city of Barkington. People are treated like trash and the "bad ones" get sorted out rather quickly. If your human doesn't do as he was told you might aswell get a replacement. "The dog's lead" is literally a block of lead James has to carry around in order to have his movement hindered. If he was to walk around without it the police would shut him down and James would be euthanized. James has to say the dogs name so he can fetch the lead block and attach it to his collar.

Answer (score 0):

> The lead is protected by a voice password, which is the dog's name. And he is blind, so he can't leave his house without his dog